# Javascript alert after for loop is not working

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, onclick

I have this code:

```
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('rich-table-row');

document.getElementById("suma").onclick = function suma(){

   var calcule = 0;  

   for(var i = 1; i < txt.length; i++) {

    calcule +=  Number(((txt[i].getElementsByClassName('rich-table-cell')[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText).substring(2)).replace(',',''));

   }

alert('test');

};
```

After the for loop ends, alert is not showing. What I am doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your for loop is excecuting, or even control is entering the `suma` function ? You can know that by just `console.log();` while entering function suma.

Also check your console.

Comment: There is probably a javascript error waiting for you in the console.

Comment: Nothing. Check your browser console for typo errors... And by the way, arrays are zero based

Comment: What happens if you `alert(txt)` before the loop?

Comment: @OmSao I am sure that is executing because if I will put the "alert" inside the loop, I will heve all the alerts till loop is finishing

Comment: @James how can I see what's going on in the console, I see no error there (mozilla - ctrl+shift+k)

Comment: @KevinBoucher it is showing me what is in "txt" innerHTML

Comment: By the way... I am using Greasemonkey on Firefox to change some things visualy... I forgot to mention

Comment: Does the number have more than one comma in it, you will need to use a regex, eg `.replace(/,/g, '')` if so.  I don't think that will prevent the alert though.

Comment: Can you include the relevant markup?

Answer (score 0):

As @James mentioned, if you are trying to remove more than one comma, than you will need to use a regular expression defined as *global*. However, like he said, this should not prevent the function from continuing (only cause `calcule` to be `NaN`).

Without the markup it's hard to say what the issue is, but my suspicion is that you have a `ReferenceError` in your code somewhere that is likely related to the markup you are trying to parse (probably not returning either the cell or the span).

I've refactored your function a little bit, including changing your call to `replace()` to use a `RegExp` and added the assumed markup; it works as expected:

JS:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('rich-table-row');

document.getElementById('suma').onclick = function () {
    var calcule = 0; 
    var cell, span, text;

    for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        cell = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('rich-table-cell')[2];
        span = cell.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        text = span.innerText.substring(2).replace(/[,]/g,'');
        calcule += Number(text);
    }

   alert(calcule);
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="rich-table">
  <div class="rich-table-row">
    <div class="rich-table-cell"></div>
    <div class="rich-table-cell"></div>
    <div class="rich-table-cell">
      <span>AB697,871,184</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rich-table-row">
    <div class="rich-table-cell"></div>
    <div class="rich-table-cell"></div>
    <div class="rich-table-cell">
      <span>AB697,871,185</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="suma">SUMA</button>
```

Comment: I get this in console: TypeError: txt[i].getElementsByClassName(...)[2] is undefined

Comment: That has to mean that your markup structure does not support the JavaScript references you are making. (I.e. There is no third instance of `rich-table-cell` on at least one of the `rich-table-row`s being referenced). Can you edit your post to include the markup?

Answer (score 0):

I think that I manage how to solve the problem...

Because of the error from console, I inseted an IF like this one if (typeof (txt[i].getElementsByClassName('rich-table-cell')[2]) != 'undefined')

I think that error is because somewhere at the end of the loop, I get undefined